# Numpy implementation of simple clustering algorithm

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to implement a simple clustering algorithm using python. First I will describe the problem:

I have some points each point is represented by an `id`, and there a pair probability between each pair i.e `prob(id1, id2)=some_value`. This is arranged in numpy array of shape `[N,3]`, where N is the number of all possible point pairs. To make more clear here is an example array:

```
a = np.array([[1,2, 0.9],
     [2,3, 0.63],
     [3,4, 0.98],
     [4,5, 0.1],
     [5,6, 0.98],
     [6,7, 1]])
```

where the first two entries are the point ids and the third entry is the probability that they belong to each other.

The clustering problem is connect points that pass probability cut `cut=0.5` i.e. points 1,2,3,4 belong to the same cluster and 5,6,7 belong to another cluster. The current solution that I have  is make a list of lists(of point ids) i.e `l=[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7]]` by looping twice over the unique point ids and array `a`. Is there a smarter and faster way to do this?

Comment: I don't see how you'd get that  result `[1,2,3,4], [5,6,7]` from the example data you've posted.

Comment: 5, 6 belong in the same cluster, making this a single cluster.

Comment: @AKX that's because `[1,2]` pass the cut `>0.5`, also `[2,3]`, `[3,4]` i.e 1,2,3 and 4 are belonging to same cluster, however `[4,5]` does not pass the cut, similarly for `[5,6,7]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you describe is a graph problem. Many common graph algorithms are implemented in the [`networkx`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/) package.

```
import numpy as np
import networkx as nx
threshold = 0.5
```

If your threshold is written in stone, you can pre-apply it, and build your [Graph](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/classes/graph.html) from the remaining data:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(a[a[:, -1] >= threshold])
```

If you want to play with your threshold in the graph, you can build with the whole array and remove edges in the graph. This will be slower than the pre-processed version:

```
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_weighted_edges_from(a)
G.remove_edges_from(e for e in g.edges if g.get_edge_data(*e) < threshold)
```

or alternatively

```
G.remove_edges_from(a[a[:, -1] < threshold]])
```

or

```
G.remove_edges_from(r for r in a if r[-1] < threshold)
```

Whether you construct a reduced graph or reduce it by removing edges, you can get the number and contents of clusters by looking at the [components](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/component.html#module-networkx.algorithms.components):

```
>>> nx.number_connected_components(G)
2
>>> for c in nx.connected_components(G):
...     print(c)
{1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0}
{5.0, 6.0, 7.0}
```

Comment: many thanks, that's works perfectly fine, just another question are there similar tools for C++?